# Error while using tab key for autocomplete in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio

this popup appears when I am using tab key for autocomplete.
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOLef.png)

I didn't even run the code, just editing, the following packages were loaded:
(tidyverse)
(xlsx)
(readxl)
(stringi)
(lubridate)
(janitor)